# Vectorized way to create a frequency vector from a set of observations in R?

Tags: c++, r

### Question

I have a vector of observations with their year of occurrence, and I want to create a vector of frequencies over a longer period for the purposes of curve fitting. I can do this easily with a function, but is there a simpler method or one that uses inherent vectorization? It may be I'm forgetting something simple.

### Reproducible example

#### Data

```
Events <- data.frame(c(1991, 1991, 1995, 1999, 2007, 2007, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2014), seq(1100, 2000, 100))
names(Events) <- c("Year", "Loss")
Period <- seq(1990, 2014)
```

#### Function

```
FreqV <- function(Period, Observations){
  n <- length(Period)
  F <- double(n)
  for(i in seq_len(n)) {
    F[i] = sum(Observations == Period[i])
  }
  return(F)
}
```

#### Expected Results

```
FreqV(Period, Events$Year)
 [1] 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 0 1
```

## Post acceptance update

It bothered me why the C++ version of the algorithm (see comments under accepted answer) was so much slower, and I finally realized that the reason was that it is a naïve translation of `FreqV` above. If there are n periods and m events, it has to do n*m calculations. Even in C++ this is slow.

Tabulate probably is set to do a one-pass algorithm, and when I code a simple one-pass algorithm in C++, it's between **5–8** times faster than tabulate:

#### Naïve C++ Code

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> FV_C(std::vector<int> P, std::vector<int> O) {
  int n = P.size();
  std::vector<int> F(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    F[i] = std::count(O.begin(), O.end(), P[i]);
  }
  return(F);
}
```

#### One-pass C++ Code

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> FV_C2(std::vector<int> P, std::vector<int> O) {
  int n = P.size();
  int m = O.size();
  int MinP = *std::min_element(P.begin(), P.end());
  std::vector<int> F(n, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
    int offset = O[i] - MinP;
    F[offset] +=  1;
  }
  return(F);
}
```

### Speed test

Tests done on an i7-2600K overclocked to 4.6Ghz with 16GB RAM using Windows 7 64bit, R-3.1.2 compiled with OpenBLAS 2.13.

```
set.seed(1)
vals <- sample(sample(10000, 100), 100000, TRUE)
period <- 1:10000

f1a <- function() tabulate(factor(vals, period), nbins = length(period))
f1b <- function() tabulate((vals-period[1])+1, nbins = length(period))
f2 <- function() unname(table(c(period, vals))-1)

library(microbenchmark)

all.equal(f1a(), f1b(), f2(), FV_C(period, vals), FV_C2(period, vals))
[1] TRUE

microbenchmark(f1a(), f1b(), f2(), FV_C(period, vals), FV_C2(period, vals), times = 100L)

Unit: microseconds
                expr        min          lq       mean     median          uq        max neval
               f1a()  26998.194  27812.6250  29515.375  28167.645  28703.4515  55456.079   100
               f1b()    640.049    712.4235   1291.356    800.136   1522.0890  27814.561   100
                f2()  34228.449  35746.6655  39686.660  36210.395  36768.3900  65295.374   100
  FV_C(period, vals) 647577.794 647927.3040 648729.027 648221.417 648848.5090 659463.813   100
 FV_C2(period, vals)    140.877    147.7270    169.085    158.449    170.3625   1095.738   100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend `factor` and `table` or `tabulate`.

Here's `tabulate`:

```
tabulate(factor(Events$Year, Period))
#  [1] 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 0 1
```

It might even be faster to do something like:

```
tabulate((Events$Year-Period[1])+1)
```

For both of these, you should probably specify `nbins`, (`nbins = length(Period)`) in case the maximum value in "Events$Year" is less than the maximum value in "Period".

---

Here's a performance comparison:

```
set.seed(1)
vals <- sample(sample(10000, 100), 100000, TRUE)
period <- 1:10000

f1a <- function() tabulate(factor(vals, period), nbins = length(period))
f1b <- function() tabulate((vals-period[1])+1, nbins = length(period))
f2 <- function() unname(table(c(period, vals))-1)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1a(), f1b(), f2())
# Unit: microseconds
#   expr       min        lq      mean    median         uq       max neval
#  f1a() 41784.904 43665.394 46789.753 44278.093  45654.546  95032.59   100
#  f1b()   884.465  1162.254  2261.118  1275.154   2756.922  46641.87   100
#   f2() 54837.666 57615.562 71386.516 58863.272 100893.389 130235.33   100
```

Comment: Could you please add akrun's solutions for reference?

Comment: @MaratTalipov, they are all slower, and I didn't want to do so until I had cross checked that they are giving the same results.

Comment: @MaratTalipov, The first option brought my system to a crawl on the sample data here (granted, I don't have the fastest system). Just looking at what each approach would be doing, the only one that looks promising is the `findInterval` + `diff` approach, but that would probably also take a performance hit from requiring `sort`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto It is not easy to compete with `tabulate` :-)  Another option that improves the speed is `library(fastmatch); fakrun <- function() tabulate(fmatch(vals, period), nbins=length(period))` `identical(fakrun(), f1b())
#[1] TRUE`

Comment: @akrun, the mean and median for that approach seems to match `f1b()`. Can't +1 again though :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yesterday, it was a bit late, so I only checked `system.time`,   You must be right.  Not much special about that approach, then :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto I converted the original `FreqV` code into C++ using Rcpp, and tabulate is still almost **1000** times as fast. Why would that be? Code is `#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector> 
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> FV_C(std::vector<int> P, std::vector<int> O) {
   int n = P.size();
   std::vector<int> F(n);
   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
     F[i] = std::count(O.begin(), O.end(), P[i]);
   }
   return(F);
}`

Comment: @Avraham, that might be a question for Dirk. I don't have experience with Rccp.

Comment: @akrun, you've broken through to the top 20 all time. Congrats! What's next?  ;-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I figured out why the translation was so fast; it was doing n loops. I've updated the question with a one-pass c++ version which is even faster than `tabulate`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
colSums(Vectorize(function(x) x==Events$Year)(Period))
#[1] 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 0 1
```

Or

```
colSums(outer(Events$Year, Period, FUN=function(x,y) x==y))
#[1] 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 0 1
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(Period, Events$Year)[, V3:=V1][, sum(V1==V2), V3]$V1
#[1] 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 0 1
```

Or if it is ordered

```
 c(0,diff(findInterval(Period,Events$Year)))
 #[1] 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 0 1
```

Or using a combination of `tabulate` with `fmatch`

```
 library(fastmatch)
 tabulate(fmatch(Events$Year, Period), nbins=length(Period))
 #[1] 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem with `table`:

```
table(c(Period,Events$Year))-1

# 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 
#    0    2    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0 
# 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 
#    3    0    0    0    1
```

To get rid of the names, use:

```
unname(table(c(Period,Events$Year))-1)
# [1] 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 0 1
```